# ¿Cómo hacer un código donde se pueda subir de nivel en positivo y bajar de nivel en negativo, con Python?

Tags: python, algoritmos

Intento crear lo siguiente: un código donde se pueda subir y bajar de nivel, donde cada vez que se sube de nivel la experiencia máxima aumente, provocando que el siguiente nivel sea un poco mas difícil de alcanzar. Existen puntos de experiencia negativos que restan experiencia y hacen que bajes de nivel, cada vez que bajas de nivel la experiencia máxima debe volver a su máximo anterior y así sucesivamente; al bajar de nivel y llegar al nivel cero pasa lo siguiente: si se sigue ganando puntos de experiencia negativos entonces el nivel pasa a nivel -1, la experiencia máxima también aumenta en negativo; cada vez que se pasa un nivel negativo, se hará mas difícil pasar de nivel en negativo.

Aquí esta el código que intenté recrear.

```
amor_punt=5
amor_maxi=5
amor_mini=-5
amor_nivel=1

def bajar_amor(): 
        while amor_punt <=amor_mini:
            if amor_maxi==0 or amor_mini==0:
                amor_maxi=-1
                amor_mini=-1
            else:
                amor_nivel -= 1 
                amor_punt-=amor_maxi*-1
                amor_mini=amor_maxi*-1
                amor_maxi-=1

def subir_amor():
        while amor_punt>=amor_maxi:
            amor_nivel += 1 
            amor_punt-=amor_maxi
            amor_maxi+=1
```

La idea es que mientras sea positivo es porque ha ganado amor, y si decrece es porque está ganando odio, por consecuencia el odio sube nivel también al igual que el amor.

Answer (score 0):

Para esto he creado 2 funciones, una encargada de subir de nivel y otra encargada de bajar de nivel, ambas tienen la misma lógica y pude haber mezclado todo en una sola función pero decidí tenerlo separado. Primero empezamos definiendo nuestras variables que serán:

- `nivel`: El nivel actual en el que nos encontramos.
- `puntaje`: Nuestro puntaje **total** actual.
- `maximo`: El puntaje máximo del nivel.
- `puntaje_nivel`: Puntaje **propio** del nivel.

La diferencia entre `puntaje` y `puntaje_nivel` radica en que si nosotros estamos en el nivel 2 tendremos un puntaje propio de ese nivel, por ejemplo `20`, pero para haber llegado hasta ese punto debimos de completar el nivel 1 con un puntaje maximo se 100 por lo que nuestro puntaje total es `120` y esto está contenido en la variable `puntaje`.

Todas estas variables las declaramos con un *scope* global para poder modificarlas dentro de las funciones e inicializamos su valor.

```py
global nivel
global maximo
global puntaje
global puntaje_nivel

maximo = 100 #el maximo del nivel 0 es 100 pntos
nivel = 0 #el nivel inicia en 0
puntaje = 0 #el puntaje inicia en 0
puntaje_nivel = 0 #el puntaje inicial del primer nivel es 0
```

Ambas funciones son fáciles de codificar, solo basta poner un `if` para indicar cuando se subirá de nivel y la dificultad de llegar al otro nivel.

```py
def subir():
    #definimos nuestras variables globales
    global nivel
    global maximo
    global puntaje
    global puntaje_nivel

    #si llegamos al máximo del nivel
    if puntaje_nivel == maximo:
        nivel += 1 #aumentamos un nivel
        maximo += 20 #aumentamos el puntaje máximo para pasar de nivel
    puntaje +=20 #aumentmos nuestro puntaje

    puntaje_nivel = puntaje-(100*nivel) #calculamos el puntaje del nivel
    # print(f"puntaje de nivel:{puntaje_nivel}")
```

No hay mucho que explicar, pues el único truco esta en el `if` que nos subirá de nivel y aumentará la dificultad. Hacemos los mismo para bajar de nivel.

```py
def bajar():
    # definimos nuestras variable globales
    global nivel
    global maximo
    global puntaje
    global puntaje_nivel

    #si el puntaje es 0, osea estamos en el inicio de un nivel
    if puntaje_nivel == 0: 
        nivel -= 1 #bajamos el nivel
        maximo -= 20 #bajamos el puntaje máximo para pasar de nivel
    puntaje -=20 #bajamos nuestro puntaje

    puntaje_nivel = puntaje-(100*nivel)
    print(f"puntaje de nivel:{puntaje_nivel}")
```

Ahora solo tenemos que ejecutar cada función dependiendo de lo que queramos, ya sea subir o bajar el nivel.

```py
while True:
    op = input("1. Subir de nivel \n0.Bajar de nivel \nS para salir")
    
    if op == "1": subir()
    elif op == "0": bajar()
    elif op.lower() == "s": break
    print(f"puntaje total:{puntaje} nivel:{nivel}  maximo={maximo}")
```

Comment: Hola Christian, gracias por responder, hay un problema, el puntaje viene del exterior, ósea, no deben sumarse dentro de la función, las funciones solo deben recibir los puntos obtenidos para aumentar o disminuir el nivel y experiencia, tal como en el ejemplo, en ese caso, ¿Qué pasa si el puntaje recibido es 500? la función debe una y otra vez aumentar de nivel hasta agotar los puntos sobrantes en el máximo de experiencia.

Comment: @Lolita Como yo lo veo, ha respondido correctamente a lo que está escrito en la pregunta.

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa Es que yo sumo o resto los puntos fuera de la función y luego se envia a la función para que determine si subir o bajar de nivel segun los puntos adquiridos previamente, porque tengo la variable puntaje dentro de condicionales en otro codigo que contiene puntaje+=20, o puntaje+=300, de manera que el puntaje no es estático como en el ejemplo, no puedo pasar las condicionales con los puntajes a esa función porque dañaria el codigo que tengo que determina cuando se gana o pierde puntos.